How could I change the colour of R ggcorrplot to grey?
I want to publish a scientific article, but for the printed version I need the figures black and white.
I cannot do this with ggcorrplot(). I tried this:
ggcorrplot(mod, show.diag=FALSE, type="lower", lab=TRUE, lab_size=3, tl.cex=7) + 
  scale_colour_grey(start = 0.8, end = 0.2) 

but it did not change the colours. I also tried this:
ggcorrplot(mod, show.diag=FALSE, type="lower", lab=TRUE, lab_size=3, tl.cex=7) + 
  scale_fill_grey()

but I received the following error:

Scale for fill is already present.
Adding another scale for fill, which will replace the existing scale.
Error in scale_fill_grey():
! Continuous values supplied to discrete scale.
ℹ Example values: -0.23, -0.2, -0.1, -0.12, and -0.17


Assign the low, mid and high correlation values using the colors parameter:
ggcorrplot(
  mod, 
  show.diag=FALSE, 
  type="lower", 
  lab=TRUE, 
  lab_size=3, 
  tl.cex=7,
  colors = c("#5f5f5f", "#9f9f9f", "#efefef"),
  ) 

